# Flink TimeStamp, adding calculated field in a stream

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

i have an out-of-ordered stream and i need to order them and sum a field value with the same field in the next frame. My code:

```
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
DataStream<Message> messageswithTS = messages.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new TimeLagWaterMarkGenerator());
DataStream<Message> SumNumber = messageswithTS 
            .keyBy("deviceId")
            .map(new Sumalo())
```

where `Sumalo()`is the function where the addition is made. The code to extract TimeStamps:

```
public class TimeLagWaterMarkGenerator implements AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks<Message> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private long currentMaxTimestamp;

@Override
public long extractTimestamp(Message element, long previousElementTimestamp) {
    long timestamp = element.getDate();
    currentMaxTimestamp = Math.max(timestamp, currentMaxTimestamp);
    return timestamp;
}

@Override
public Watermark getCurrentWatermark() {
    return new Watermark(currentMaxTimestamp);
}
}
```

The result:

```
1   TRUE    0   21  1473861657491   6af7ecfb-5122-48b6-ada1-0ea39d1d4740
1   FALSE   3   3   1473861657496   c8b4617d-534b-4c5e-825c-a8c5556fcd87
1   TRUE    1   29  1473861657497   f5b72056-ec3d-4c97-b86d-73ed728757c3
1   FALSE   0   29  1473861657501   363d061d-ce02-4709-9683-b3bb233861f3
....
```

The correct result:

```
1   TRUE    0   0   1473861657491   6af7ecfb-5122-48b6-ada1-0ea39d1d4740
1   FALSE   3   3   1473861657496   c8b4617d-534b-4c5e-825c-a8c5556fcd87
1   TRUE    1   4   1473861657497   f5b72056-ec3d-4c97-b86d-73ed728757c3
1   FALSE   0   4   1473861657501   363d061d-ce02-4709-9683-b3bb233861f3
....
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Flink does *not* automatically sort an event-time stream on event-time and does also *not* provide an operator to sort an event-time stream (which would only possible on the event-time, i.e., to convert an out-of-order stream into an in-order stream).

However, you can implement such an operator yourself by extending the `AbstractStreamOperator`. This is a low-level interface at which you have access to events, their assigned timestamps, and received watermarks. The operator could work as follows. It could insert all arriving elements into a heap which is sorted by event time. When a watermark arrives, it emits all elements with timestamps less than the watermark. In case a late element arrives (i.e., an element whose timestamp is less than the current watermark) you can either emit it (destroying the complete order of the stream) or discard it. The operator would also need to participate in checkpointing by keeping the heap as Flink managed state. You should be aware that this interface is very low-level and requires a good understanding of how Flink works. In addition, it might change between minor versions.

Regarding your timestamp and watermark assigner, you are not adding any slack to the watermarks. With this implementation you will likely have many late elements. Have a look at the `BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor`.

Comment: Thank you Fabian, any other alternative? I tried it with Table API and SQL features, but aggregate on stream tables is currently not supported...

Comment: No. Unfortunately, that's the only possible way to implement it at the moment. This feature will be added to the Table API in the future.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer already pointed out, you need to create a custom operator in your transform operation on the stream. I found [this](https://github.com/dataArtisans/flink-training-exercises/blob/master/src/main/java/com/dataartisans/flinktraining/examples/datastream_java/process/CarEventSort.java) link very helpful in solving a similar problem that I was chasing.